# Recreate Same Security Group Rule Each time I execute "terrafrom apply/plan"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Without making any changes to main.tf, Terraform add already existing security group rules.
Terrafrom Identifies each SG rules in main.tf as a new rule(but these rules are already in aws as a result of previous execution)and try to recreate them when I execute the command(terrafrom plan/apply)

This is output of terraform apply command

```
~ module.application_sg.aws_security_group.security_group
    ingress.#:                            "3" => "1"
    ingress.2358522502.cidr_blocks.#:     "1" => "0"
    ingress.2358522502.cidr_blocks.0:     "20.0.1.0/24" => ""
    ingress.2358522502.from_port:         "443" => "0"
    ingress.2358522502.protocol:          "tcp" => ""
    ingress.2358522502.security_groups.#: "0" => "0"
    ingress.2358522502.self:              "false" => "false"
    ingress.2358522502.to_port:           "443" => "0"
    ingress.3250959853.cidr_blocks.#:     "1" => "0"
    ingress.3250959853.cidr_blocks.0:     "20.0.1.0/24" => ""
    ingress.3250959853.from_port:         "8080" => "0"
    ingress.3250959853.protocol:          "tcp" => ""
    ingress.3250959853.security_groups.#: "0" => "0"
    ingress.3250959853.self:              "false" => "false"
    ingress.3250959853.to_port:           "8080" => "0"
    ingress.753360330.cidr_blocks.#:      "0" => "0"
    ingress.753360330.from_port:          "0" => "0"
    ingress.753360330.protocol:           "-1" => "-1"
    ingress.753360330.security_groups.#:  "0" => "0"
    ingress.753360330.self:               "true" => "true"
    ingress.753360330.to_port:            "0" => "0"

+ module.rule1.aws_security_group_rule.rule
    cidr_blocks.#:            "1"
    cidr_blocks.0:            "20.0.1.0/24"
    from_port:                "80"
    protocol:                 "tcp"
    security_group_id:        "sg-17c13770"
    self:                     "false"
    source_security_group_id: "<computed>"
    to_port:                  "80"
    type:                     "ingress"
```

This rules is already existing one.Please help to avoid this as this is very difficult to understand when we are going to add new rules to environment.

Answer (score 1):

Check the state file. This normally happens when Terraform has applied the changes but hasn't updated the state file.

You can list what's in the state file for the location by using:

```
terraform state list
```

If it's missing in the state file you should be able to use Terraform's import command to import the pre-existing resource into the state file with something like:

```
terraform import aws_security_group.security_group sg-123456
```

Comment: But when I execute the terraform refresh command it doesn't detect any changes.Its mean that terraform state file and real Infrastructure is same.
but when I execute terraform apply or paln it tries to add security group rules which already exist as a result of previous terraform execution.I want to avoid this because when I really want to add a new rule I can get misunderstand or hard to find out what is really newly added rule

Comment: If you look at the state file does it show it at all? Refresh only updates Terraform's view of resources that it is managing (such as the configuration of an ELB built by TF but changed outside of TF). If it's not in the state file at all then a refresh doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put ingress/egress rule in `aws_security_group` object. Use `aws_security_group_rule` to manage the rules.

eg.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my-secret-group" {
  name = "my-secret-group"
  vpc_id = "vpc-12345678"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ssh-external-to-node" {
  type = "ingress"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.my-secret-group.id}"
  from_port = 22
  to_port = 22
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "http-external-to-node" {
  type = "ingress"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.my-secret-group.id}"
  from_port = 80
  to_port = 80
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem above for me, but it would be useful to understand why